# Unable To Configure Visual Studio 2013 to Connect to Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, server, foundation

I'm trying to connect Visual Studio 2013 to TFS 2013 from a different machine, but it's giving me error: 
(TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server).
The Server's IP is working, so the server is online, I've tried things such as turning off Firewall, starting VS as Administrator and it doesn't seem to work.

It's the first time I'm working with TFS, am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **As a part of the team I also want to mention something:** The server is on a separate machine. On this machine everything seems to be ok. I even tried to turn off the firewall and the antivirus protection but we're getting the same error again. The VS on the machine with the TFS is connecting with no problem. Like Blaskowiz said, we're first time TFS users with 0 exerience. :)

Comment: Did you try the troubleshooting as provided by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the troubleshooting by MSDN, but I still can't connect to TFS

Comment: When I tried to change the password it is giving me an error: "The account specified for this service account is a system account. You cannot change the password for a system account."

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting via telnet, e.g `telnet yourserver 8080` at the command prompt: this checks if the client has TCP/IP connectivity. Telnet client is not installed by default in Windows, so you may have to turn the corresponding Windows Feature on.

If previous check passes, open the Home page in a browser, e.g. `http://yourserver:8080/tfs`. If the browser is not configured for Integrated authentication, you will receive a prompt for credential. Insert a valid user and the home page should appear.

Consider which credential you are using: if TFS server is in workgroup, use an account defined on the TFS server; if TFS server is joined to Active Directory, use an account from the same domain. In any case the account must be part of TFS *Valid Users* group.